# Link the open file to file system tree in c9 IDE

Tags: editor, settings, cloud9-ide

In `C9 IDE`, when I open a file, is it possible to expand the file system tree to that file.

I need something similar to "[Link with Editor](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse/images/xeditorsyncpackage10.png.pagespeed.ic.KwsxqJhxG1.png)" button of `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use Cmd-Shift-L on a mac (I think it's Ctrl-Shift-L on win/linux). There's also a setting to do this automatically as a tab becomes active. You can also right click on a tab and choose "reveal in file tree"

Comment: "There's also a setting to do this automatically as a tab becomes active. ", can you explain more about this?

Comment: By turning on the setting, the file loaded in the active tab will be highlighted in the tree. Check out this screenshot to find the setting toggle: http://screencast.com/t/dxipjlB3N